# ASP.NET MVC Razor - How to access database from your section?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

For example my app has the table name "menu" in database.
I creat a section for menu-bar that will be call in Layout. But I not sure how to access database from that!

By the way....any one can tell me how to access model's data from your custom helper?
Any advise?

Answer (score 2):

MVC3 comes with Entity Framework, which allows you to map entity classes to your database schema.

You query your database using Entity Framework in your View Controller. Then pass the result as the model to your View.

I suggest reading some of the tutorials out there to get started if you don't understand what I just posted.

Comment: Ofcource I can load the data to ViewBag.MyMenu and pass it to view. But the menu will load for each controllers so I finding a way that help me avoid repeat my code...and a helper will help..i thought...

Comment: I believe you're looking for Partials. They allow you to define a common template that can be included in each view.